# How to write a loop that select values containing a pattern and modifies them in r

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, indexing

I am trying to write a loop that, given a list of indices "list_idx" of the values that contain a certain pattern, say "P", does the following:

1)Iterates over a column of the dataset
2) For all elements in the column, if their index belongs to list_idx, does the following:

- It removes the pattern "P" from the value,
- It converts the value to an integer,
- It multiplies the number obtained per 100.

I am stuck at the beginning of the second part. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried:

```
for (i in list_idx){
    Dataset$column[i] <- str_remove(Dataset$column, "K")
    Dataset$column[i] <- (as.integer(Dataset$column[i]))*100}
```

and I get as error:

"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items..."

Comment: Possible to include sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may not need to loop here i.e. `str_remove` is vectorized and it doesn't need to loop over each element of the 'column'.  Instead, we can subset the 'column' based on the index in 'list_idx', remove the "K", convert to `integer`, multiply by 100 and update it back

```
library(stringr)
Dataset$column[list_idx] <- as.integer(str_remove(Dataset$column[list_idx], "K")) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you! It did solve a big part of the problem indeed! The only thing, most of the values whose index belong to the list now have been substituted with 0 or NA. 

     [1] NA  "0" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "0" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "0" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "0" "0" NA  NA 
 [34] "0" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "0" "0" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "0" NA  "0" NA  NA  NA ...

Might this have to do with the conversion to integer?

Comment: Solved! By converting to numeric, with as.numeric() before multiplying per 100 it worked, and then I can convert the result to integer.

Thanks you a lot for your help!!!